# Control An Application With Using Another Application

Tags: java, android

I have a question about controlling applications in Android. I want to develop an application which selects appropriate network bands for each application. I guess i have to grant superuser access but i have another problem. Is there any available java code to do that?? Is there any library or something that you know? How can i do that?

I can list apps in a listview but i want controll them with an switch. There must be connection with the applications by switch

Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

It' easier then what you think. Check out android intents [(here)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) [(and here)](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/sending.html). Intents are a kind of an event bus provided by android framework that can be used to launch applications as well as activities/services/receivers

Comment: Thanks for the information. I know that intends are the connection between two activity. If we can reach an application, i can do that :) Thanks

Comment: Also i mean my settings which selected from my application controls the other. For example: I want to use youtube with always 3G, when i open youtube, 3G selected because of my settings because of my application. Thats what i mean

Comment: you can pass arbitrary data beetween components thanks to put/getExtras, then you can start an activity from another application if this activity declares an "action" in its intent filter. Intent filter are those things that say "this app react to that intent". Of course, you need to alunch the main activity from the application chosen from your user